# Да, было плохо видно, но она тебя точно пристрелила бы

Tags: наклонение

> Да, было плохо видно, **но она тебя точно пристрелила бы**.

Англичанин передал эту фразу так:

> *......, she was going to kill jou.*

Хочу дать следующее объяснение, но не хватает уверенности в правильности моей мысли: 
Не согласна с английским переводчиком, потому что "to be going to" передает намерение. В русском оригинале выражется не намерение (=она хотела его убить), а гипотетичность ситуации - она убила бы его, если бы было светлее. Так? Или есть другои вид чтения сослагательного наклонения в этом случае?

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У переводчика *были* основания для такого варианта перевода.  Выделенная часть русского предложения выражает не предположение о *её намерениях*, а *убеждённость* в направлении хода *событий* (напр. в случае бездействия) в ситуации из прошлого. Таков же и *один* из возможных смыслов, выражаемых с помощью *is/was going to*.

Соответствующее толкование из словаря Cambridge Dictionary: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/future/future-be-going-to-i-am-going-to-work

> *We use be going to **predict** something that we think is certain to happen...* (Мы используем выражение be going to для **предсказания** того,
>   что считаем **неизбежным**)

В нашем случае такое предсказание перенесено в
прошлое: говорящий *был уверен* в том, к чему именно всё идёт (она точно пристрелила бы).

Comment: перевела это предложение на мой язык и удивилась =) мы тоже использовали бы прошедшее время
большое спасибо за помощь всем!

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы уверенно ответить на Ваш вопрос, немного не хватает контекста ситуации. Ваша трактовка не совсем подходит к этому предложению. "Сослагательная" трактовка подошла бы к такому предложению:

> Да, было плохо видно, **иначе** она тебя точно пристрелила бы.

или к такому:

> Да, было плохо видно, **а то** она тебя точно пристрелила бы.

Поэтому, чтобы допустить Вашу трактовку, нужно предположить, что в русском оригинале допущена ошибка или неточность.

Но возможен контекст ситуации, в которой эта фраза прозвучит корректно и её лучше перевести именно намерением, я думаю.

Не могли бы Вы описать ситуацию подробнее?

**Дополнение.**

Пример ситуации, о которой я говорю, встречается в книге "Азазель" Б. Акунина.

Answer (score 2):

**Первая ситуация:** снайпер была на месте, но темнота помешала (об этой ситуации уже сказано).

**Вторая возможная ситуация выглядит так**: снайпера не было на том месте, но что было бы, если бы она была там).

Диалог:

- Было плохо видно, поэтому вряд ли она меня пристрелила бы.
- **Да, видно было плохо, но (тем не менее) она тебя точно пристрелила бы.**

То есть даже темнота  не помешала бы.

Answer (score 1):

В английском языке оборот to be going to имеет несколько значений: намерение, уверенности,заранее запланированного действия.

А в прошедшем времени оборот употребляется для обозначения действия, которое должно было произойти, но не произошло.

Ср.: He was going to enter the Institute but then changed his mind – он собирался поступить в институт, но потом передумал.

Сослагательное наклонение точно передает это значение.  Переводчик абсолютно верно перевел это предложение.